# Avoid horizontal scroll, and center content on mobile devices

Tags: scroll, responsive-design, zooming, viewport

I have a static layout (750px width) and I'm trying to make it renders centered and disable the horizontal scroll as well.

I did dozens of searches in google, tried lots of different viewport settings but nothing worked.

This is the site: www.motocross.es

Comment: Did you fix this already?

Answer (score 0):

estilos_2012.css lines 18 and 11 have a min-width: 1200px for your body. take those off and your problem is solved.

also if you want to disable horizontal scroll an overflow-x: hidden on the element you want to prevent scrolling would do the trick. read more about it [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have `min-width:1200px` on your body.